# Exchange API does not return shared calendar which are shared on other domain

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I am using EWS Managed exchange api in c#.
When I fetch all calendar using below code, it's not returning me all calendar.
It's only return my calendarm but there is more calendar which are shared by other.

```
SearchFilter sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(
    FolderSchema.FolderClass, "IPF.Appointment");

FindFoldersResults ffoldres = service.FindFolders(
    new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, "emailId"),
    sfSearchFilter, fvFolderView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have calendar call as below. 
service.FindFolders(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, "email")

In this call we pass my email id. (My credential email).
If i need to access other user calendar(Shared calendar). I need to pass other user email address here. like service.FindFolders(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, "Other user email").

Service object is created by my credential and just pass email of other user. Now you can get all calendar.